# Adding product to pricing table dynamically and post to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

few day ago i coded a product addition in table and calculating it total cost as pr addition of product and submit the list in database bit when i am adding(selecting )the products in the billing table, the name of those addition products are not getting posted,this i get by profiling my result here is my code ::

controller:

```
    $common['extra_fee_list']='';    
        $sql2="SELECT * FROM fee_additional_fee";
         $query2 = $this->db->query($sql2);
        foreach ($query2->result_array() as $row2)
        {
        $common['extra_fee_list']=$common['extra_fee_list'].' <tr>  <td>  
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="additional_fee_code[]"  value="'.$row2['id'].'"/> </td>  
        <td>'.$row2['cause_addition_fee'].'</td> <td>'.$row2['fee'].'</td>  </tr>  '; //here agin plz take input in  arry ----additional_fee_code will work for next method (cal_total_extra_fee())

        } // name (additional_fee_code[]) not getting posted 
//this code id only for printing the list to be added
```

here is my view::

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('fee_related/cal_total_extra_fee')?>">

                    <div class="block-content">
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <div class="_25">
                <?php echo form_dropdown('class', $dropdown_class); ?>
                                    <?php echo form_dropdown('section',$dropdown_section); ?>
</div>  
    <table id="table-example" class="table">

    <tr>
        <th>Cause</th>
        <th>Monthly Charge</th>
    </tr>
     <tbody id="selectedServices"></tbody>

    <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td id="total">1500</td> <!-- get the value from datbase and also in javascript!-->
    </tr>

</table>    
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <div class="block-actions">
                            <ul class="actions-left">
                                <li><a class="button red" id="reset-validate-form" href="javascript:void(0);">Reset</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="actions-right">
                                <li><input type="submit" class="button" value="Alot!!"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    </form>
```

and JS:

```
<script src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <SCRIPT language="javascript">
$(function () {
    $(":checkbox").change(function () {
        // Toggle class of selected row
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("rowSelected");

        // Get all items name, sum total amount
        var sum = 1500;
        var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function () {
            sum += Number($(this).parents('tr').find('td:last').text());
            return $(this).parents('tr').clone();
        }).get();

        // Display selected items and their sum
        $("#selectedServices").html(arr).find('input').remove();
        $("#total").text(sum);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not quite enough information to give you a proper answer here, but if I read you right, your main issue is that you are not getting the id into your generated HTML in the first panel.  Try inserting:  echo ($row2['id']."<BR>"); into your foreach loop.  It is also worth echoing htmlspecialchars($your_output_string) as this will usually reveal where the missing data is.  Try this and get back to us.

Comment: no i am getting row as well as name..but on selecting the product..in that calculation table m not getting the name="" and value=""  of selected product..